# InputStream.close() takes too long to finish (time relative to size of file)

Tags: java, inputstream

I am using the LiveSDK and I was debugging some stuff related canceling a download and came across a strange behavior: when the InputStrem.close() is called it takes really long, proportional to the file size that was being downloaded, in other methods that I wrote for downloading files from the internet when I close the InputStream it closes instantly, so this is really strange to me.
Does anybody have an idea why this could happen?

I came across this [link](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4211025) that may somebody help to understand the problem, but I couldn't.

Comment: What operating system? What filesystem? How large are the files?

Comment: The link to the Bug report was for Java 1.1 and was fixed 13 years ago, so unless you are using a version of java less than Java 1.4  I don't think it is the same bug.

Comment: It's java 1.6 on Android. The size of the files are different, as I wrote "proportional to file size" It may start to take long with 2-5 MB

Comment: And why do you downgrade my question? I must start somewhere with my question, I don't know what more data would be relevant to aaaaall the people consider this a good question

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the used stream was a ContentLengthInputStream where the documentation says following:

"Note that this class NEVER closes the underlying stream, even when close gets called. Instead, it will read until the "end" of its limit on close, which allows for the seamless execution of subsequent HTTP 1.1 requests, while not requiring the client to remember to read the entire contents of the response."

I didn't find a documentation or something that helps me understand how this class really works, but it's really not intuitive that the close method of this class doesn't really close it. To force stopping the download **HttpApiRequest.abort()** must be called and the InputStream will close automatically.

Comment: Thanks. I am also facing this issue where InputStream is not getting closed from HttpEntity. I was downloading a file stream of 30 GB.

Comment: is there any undesirable effect of aborting the HTTP requests?